# What is the word or term used to describe doing an activity or work with a high level of concentration and intention, trying your best?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

It would be similar to trying to be extremely careful or precise.

In French it would be "application", For example: "Qui est fait avec application".

Example usage:

John worked with ________.
or
...it was done with _______.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***diligent***](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/appliqu%C3%A9)

> *adj.* Marked by persevering, painstaking effort.
>
> **diligence**
>
> Earnest and persistent application to an undertaking; steady effort; assiduity.
>
> [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Diligent)
>
> *Final tasks that had been neglected for months, and in some cases years, were being done with diligence under Jenny's eyes*
>
> [Google Books](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22done+with+diligence%22&biw=522&bih=342&tbm=bks&ei=St7kVsrNCYvfUaPgvoAD&start=20&sa=N&dpr=2)

Comment: I don't think there is a proper single word translation to English, but "diligent" and "assiduity" combined with "earnest" comes close. Answer accepted.

Comment: Another good word I found: sedulous.  "He was sedulous in his work".

Answer (score 1):

**Meticulous**

> [Meticulous](https://www.google.com/search?q=meticulous&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=define%20meticulous) - showing great attention to detail; very careful and precise.

**Scrupulous**

> [Scrupulous](https://www.google.com/search?q=meticulous&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=define%20scrupulous) - diligent, thorough, and extremely attentive to details.

Answer (score 1):

***assiduous***

Defined by the American Heritage® Dictionary<sup>1</sup> as quoted by [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/assiduous):

> Showing or characterized by persistent attention or untiring application: *an assiduous worker who strove for perfection; did assiduous research before writing the book*.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sup><sub>American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.</sub></sup>

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Can you try to include reference or link (that can support your answer) and its essential part? Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Answer (score 0):

You can say that you're performing the activity with *[focus](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/focus_2)*:

> **focus**, *n.*: the act of concentrating on a particular goal and not wasting time or energy on other things

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom LOL, thanks, I've certainly been on the other end of that often enough...

Comment: If you wanted to focus (haha) even further on how extremely careful and precise the person is being, you could even say they're **laser-focused**.